# Controlling JFrame from JMenuBar

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to maximize JFrame from within JMenuBar, I can not pass a reference to the frame. Is it possible to get a reference to the frame that it is used in?

i can get to the top level component but it does not have a way to maximize and minimize   frame.

```
    public Container getApplicationFrame(ActionEvent event){
         JMenuItem menuItem = (JMenuItem) event.getSource();  
         JPopupMenu popupMenu = (JPopupMenu) menuItem.getParent();  
         Component invoker = popupMenu.getInvoker(); 
         JComponent invokerAsJComponent = (JComponent) invoker;  
         Container topLevel = invokerAsJComponent.getTopLevelAncestor();  
         return topLevel;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the Window that contains the JPanel via

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(popupMenu);
```

You can then either maximise it using `window.setSize()` -- or, since you seem to know that it's a JFrame, cast it to Frame and use the `setExtendedState` method that Kevin mentions. [Example code](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt/frame_FrameIconify.html) from the Java Developers' Almanac for that:

```
// This method minimizes a frame; the iconified bit is not affected
public void maximize(Frame frame) {
    int state = frame.getExtendedState();

    // Set the maximized bits
    state |= Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;

    // Maximize the frame
    frame.setExtendedState(state);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can stash the frame in question in a local variable somewhere?

As for actually maximizing the Frame once you've got ahold of it, Frame.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH) is probably what you want. [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState(int))

While not as elegant as it could be, quick path to ground on your existing code:

```
public Frame getApplicationFrame(ActionEvent event){
         if(event.getSource() == null) return null;

         Window topLevel = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(event.getSource());

         if(!(topLevel instanceof Frame)) return null;

         return (Frame)topLevel;
}

...
//Somewhere in your code
Frame appFrame = getApplicationFrame(myEvent);
appFrame.setExtendedState(appFrame.getExtendedState() | Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
...
```

Minimum Java version 1.4.2.  Be forwarned I have not tested the above code, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The class that creates the frame and the menubar can also act as the ActionListener for the menu item, since it has access both the frame and the menubar.